# Fermionic occupation operator and nearest neighbor Fermionic hopping interaction as a qubit operator

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, chemistry, solid-state

How to express Fermionic occupation operator $(\hat{a}_j^\dagger\hat{a}_j)$ and nearest neighbor Fermionic hopping interaction ($H_h= J\sum_{i=1}\hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_{i+1}+\hat{a}_{i+1}^\dagger \hat{a}_{i})$ as a qubit operators.

Comment: Is this a one-dimensional chain (when you say "nearest neighbor")?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes

Comment: Then (to add to the answer below), the Jordan-Wigner transformation is just what you want: If will yield a NN qubit Hamiltonian. (So you can neglect the O(n))-local in the answer below.)

Comment: Could help to add this to the question!

Comment: @gIS what did you like about Norbert's answer more than mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The oldest and most commonly known way is the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation). The qubit operators will be $\mathcal{O}(N)$-local for $N$ occupiable orbitals.
- A significantly more complicated way is the [Bravyi-Kitaev transformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403025) for which the qubit operators will be $\mathcal{O}(\log N)$-local.
- There's many other ways, but the above two are by far the most important to know in the early stages of your project.

You can simply transform creation and annihilation operators into "occupied" and "unoccupied" operators:

[image]

But you have to also make sure the wavefunction satisfies the anti-symmetric property for fermions, so you have to add *strings* of $Z$ operators to count the number -1's (this is the Jordan-Wigner transformation which is $n-local$):

[image]

The occupation operator in the first part of your question is simply:

[image]

To get the other operators in your question, you can just substitute the $a_j$ and $a^\dagger_j$ expression from above.

I used this [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/libraries/chemistry/concepts/jordan-wigner) to get the equations.

Note that if your Hamiltonian has only nearest-neighbor couplings, then the issue of the JW transformation being $N$-local can be mitigated due to cancellation when multiplying (for example) $a_j$ with $a_{j+1}^\dagger$, as noted in [Norbert Schuch's comment here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16463/fermionic-occupation-operator-and-nearest-neighbor-fermionic-hopping-interaction/16465?noredirect=1#comment23090_16465).

Comment: If you have n orbitals and you get something O(n)-local, isn't that as non-local as it gets?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yea the JW transformation is significantly non-local. The Bravyi-Kitaev transformation is better if low locality is important for the user's application. Significantly more complicated though.

Comment: Well, the user is asking about a 1D spin chain with NN interaction, so JW just seems perfect.

Comment: Note that there are also some other mappings, such as a work presented at last QIP.

Comment: My answer says "There's many other ways, but the above two are by far the most important to know in the early stages of your project". Furthermore, how does the fact that the operators have nearest-neighbor couplings help? The $a^\dagger_N$ in my answer is N-local. Also the question didn't specify that the user was talking about nearest-neighbor interactions until 45 minutes ago (a day after I wrote my answer).

Comment: I know that the clarification came after your answer, since I asked for it. I am just pointing out that in the case of the question, JW is best. -- To answer your question how NN helps, note that the NN Hamiltonian only involves on-site potentials and NN hopping, in which case after the JW-trafo you get *local* spin Hamiltonians because the non-local terms in the $a_{i}$ and the $a_{i+1}^\dagger$ cancel (a well known fact in CM physics used to e.g. conversely solve the 1D quantum Ising model or [2D classical Ising model](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.36.856)!).

Comment: I added your comment to the bottom of my answer. And yes: quantum chemists don't often use the JW transformation or anything similar, and don't tend to use model Hamiltonians like the Ising or Hubbard ones. They're often trying to get the spectra of a molecule accurately enough to compare with experiments, so they try solving the Schroedinger equation for that molecule (without making Ising-like/Hubbard-like/etc. approximations). Now that companies are trying to do quantum chemistry on quantum computers, some chemists have become interested in JW-type transformations, but it's not mainstream.

Comment: I understand, no criticism intended! It was just meant as an addition to your answer. It is indeed surprising to see how different backgrounds are - for physicists, usually the reason to even *learn* about JW is to solve the Ising or XX model (so, it is really used the other way round: map a spin system to non-interacting fermions which can be solved exactly). -- BTW, interesting to see that comments can be linked!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch just click on the time stamp next to your name, and then you have the URL for linking the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation). For a 1D chain with NN interaction it will yield a spin Hamiltonian with NN interaction (specifically, the hopping will map to a XX term and the on-site term to a Z term). (In fact, part of this mapping is even given on the German Wikipedia site on the topic.)

On the other hand, if you don't want to put this on a quantum computer but solve it, you should stay in the fermionic picture (or map the spin problem to a fermionic one). This is how one solves e.g. the 1D quantum transverse field Ising model.

Finally, if you don't have 1D local Hamiltonians, considering other transformation which keep locality (or few-bodiness of the terms), such as the one mentioned in the other answer,
can make sense (in particular since local spin models are easier to simulate than those with non-local and in particular many-body interaction).