# Fermionic commutation relation using Jordan-Wigner transformation

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, chemistry, solid-state

How can one show in detailed steps that Fermionic annihilation and creation operators, under Jordan-Wigner transformation, satisfy the Fermionic commutation relations?

The Fermionic commutation relations are:
$$\{\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j\}=  \{\hat{a}_i^\dagger,\hat{a}_j^\dagger\} =0 , \{\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger\} = \delta_{ij}.$$

Comment: Do you have nearest-neighbor coupling again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my answer to this: [Fermionic occupation operator and nearest neighbor Fermionic hopping interaction as a qubit operator](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16465/2293), you can see that we have:

\begin{align}
\hat{a}_i &= \frac{1}{2}  Z^{\otimes (i-1)} (X - iY),\\
\hat{a}_i^\dagger          &=\frac{1}{2}  Z^{\otimes (i-1)} (X + iY).\\
\end{align}

If $i=j$ we have:

\begin{align}
\{\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_i^\dagger\} &\propto \frac{1}{4}  ((X - iY)(X + iY) + (X + iY)(X - iY)),\\                         &= \frac{1}{4}  (X^2 + iXY + - iXY + Y^2 +  X^2 -iXY + iXY + Y^2) \\
&=\frac{1}{4}(2X^2 + 2Y^2)\\
& =\frac{1}{4}(4I) \\
& = I.
\end{align}

All $Z$ operators are replaced by $I$ operators since $Z \times Z = I$, and this is also what was done in the penultimate step, where $X^2 = I$ and $Y^2 = I$ were used.

For the other anti-commutators we have:

\begin{align}
\{\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j\} &= \frac{1}{4}  ((X - iY)(X - iY) + (X - iY)(X - iY)),\\                         \{\hat{a}^\dagger_i,\hat{a}^\dagger_j\} &= \frac{1}{4}  ((X + iY)(X + iY) + (X + iY)(X + iY)). 
\end{align}

You can then do the same type of arithmetic that I went through in detail for the first anti-commutator.

Comment: Shouldn't the last two equations be zero? When $i=j$ this follows from the fact that $\hat{a}_i$ is [nilpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) with degree 2. When $i \ne j$, this follows from the fact that $Z$ and $X\pm iY$ anticommute (and all other operator pairs in tensor products resulting from JW commute). Am I missing something?

Comment: The question asks why they are zero. I gave the full work for the $\{ a_i , a_j^\dagger \}$ case when i=j, then showed the first line for the other two cases (still with i=j). The user asked several questions of this same nature within a couple days, and I wanted to let them do some of the work after giving some starting steps :)